# Merge values of two objects

Tags: reflection, merge, java-8

I have complex java class as shown below.

```
Class FinalValue {
List<Item> items;
List<Option> options;

Class Item/Option {
 String itemId/optionId;
 Type type;
 Rate rate;
 String currency;
}

 Class Rate {
    Integer id;
    BigDecimal rateAmount;
    Boolean isActive;
    }
 }
```

I want to merge the values of list `List<FinalValue>` to single one `FinalValue` with some conditions. Most of the values will be same even though it is list but if any values are different, need to set both values.

I am thinking to do with for loop and comparing each inner elements and set once if they are same but add all possible if they are different.

Is there any better approach to address this rather than looping to each level and add values.

Comment: Several questions... what shall the merge operation merge? What do you mean by _better_? Faster? More elegant? And what is your current approach, please add that code.

Comment: I have not coded it but current approach is use for loop and keep setting the values in new Object. If there are different values, set both of them.

Comment: And what is the concrete question?

Comment: You could do like this: 


    `FinalValue = list.stream().reduce(new FinalValue(),FinalValue::merge);`


and in `FinalValue` class you should define `merge` method. 


    `public FinalValue merge(FinalValue finalValue){
      return new FinalValue()
            .items(finalValue.getItems())
            .options(finalValue.getOptions());
    }`  and `options` can be do like this `public FinalValue options(List<Option> options){
        this.option = Stream.concat(this.option.stream(), options.stream())
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }`

Comment: Thank you, if Rate of same items is different in two objects. I want to merge them both. With above approach, how is it possible?